# Xamarin Forms relative layout - get a stack layout centred inside

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms application where I use a relative layout to get some elements positioned very specifically. I want to have a stack layout centred right in the middle of the relative layout.  I use this code:

```
_relativeLayout.Children.Add (
        _stackLayout, 
        Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => (p.Width / 2) - (_stackLayout.Width / 2) ),
        Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => (p.Height/ 2) - (_stackLayout.Height / 2) )

    );
```

When the form loads, I do not get the right result. The stack layout is way off to one side. However, if I rotate the screen one way and then back again, it looks perfect. So I gather that when the layout is rendered, the height and width of the stack layout have not yet been fully calculated, but on rotation these values are known so it renders properly.

How can I get the stack layout perfectly centred on initial form load?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the request values. Check if the Width/Height is -1 in which case it has not been initialized yet and you should use the request value. If it has been initialized then use it.

```
        this._relativeLayout.Children.Add(
            this._stackLayout, 
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => (p.Width / 2) - 
                ((this._stackLayout.Width == -1 ? this._stackLayout.WidthRequest : this._stackLayout.Width) / 2)),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => (p.Height / 2) - 
                ((this._stackLayout.Height == -1 ? this._stackLayout.HeightRequest : this._stackLayout.Height) / 2))
        );
```

Comment: So long as I give my stack layout a width and height request, this seems to work perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Cleared a very Important confusion !! Thanks a lot, I am trying to create a login screen . where i need to put "username : ______(entry element)" and password:______(element) vertically , i am not able to figure out the constraints , or its not working ! any suggestion

Comment: Any way to achieve similar behavior using Xaml?